# How to add custom Grails plugin artefact directory

Tags: grails, plugins

I have a Grails application and a custom plugin with separate code included in the main application in `BuildConfig.groovy` using `grails.plugin.location.'my-plugin' = '../my-plugin'`. Now I'm looking for a way to customize what artefact directories will be exported in the plugin. I want to place a custom resource file (e.g. SQL script) into `src/resources` directory of the plugin and I need to see the file on classpath of the main application. I know files in `grails-app/conf` and other directories get included along with the plugin source, but can the convention of resource directories be altered?

Comment: What do you mean by included along with the plguin source? You mean you want to customize the contents of the plugin? If so then I suggest you look into "Hooking into Build Events" http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/plugins.html#hookingIntoBuildEvents

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. I tried to copy the needed files in the _Install.groovy script, but it seems it is only executed after a "real" plugin install, not when the plugin is just included using `grails.plugin.location.*`. The files are still not packed within the app.

Comment: Well, since you are using inline plugins then your next option is to customize your Gant scripts for building your application.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gant scripts. Nevertheless, saying which files I want to insert to the app from a plugin directory would defeat the purpose of isolating a part of the code into a plugin. I just want the plugin to decide what content it provides.

Comment: Unfortunately since you are using an inline plugin you aren't taking full advantage of the encapsulation available to packaged plugins. It's a trade off.